# Having single API project instead of multiples API projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In application I am working on having few ASP.Net core api projects inside one visual studio solution and within each API project having several Api controllers. Lets assume those like Order.Api, Customer.Api and Product.Api. Thinking of instead of few separate projects keep one API project lets call it Backend.Api and going to move all controllers into this single project. What would be drawback on it also advantages of it?.

Comment: It would be more complex for end users to use your stuff, and more complex for you to maintain and update. But it would provide more atomic control for you.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to get an idea about the reason you had multiple api projects to start with to answer the question. You can get more insights reading about tradeoffs between micro service vs monolithic design. This is an article from Martin Fowlers blog https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-trade-offs.html

That said following may give you a high-level answer.

**Drawbacks**

- Merging the apis will take way the ability of independant
  testability, deployability and scalability of features.
- Merging the apis may result in less readable source code organisation.
- Reduced level of fault isolation.

**Advantages**

- Deployment and monitoring of the application will become much simpler.
- Ease of debugging
- Communication among customer, order, product business capabilities will be easier.

Comment: Thanks @Nisal I think scalability and deployability should be serious things, also I suspect It will also helping for more coupling as well which should be avoidable.